# Java GUIS Panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am kind of curious on how would you manage to replace a certain picture on a Grid of rows=4 and columns = 4. Let say if I had 4 images and one of them being blank, how would go on about choosing 1 random images and enabling it to be placed on any row[] and col[].

- would i need to do a Boolean logic with double nested for loops?
- This is just out of curiosity due to a question a saw here online, I tried attempting it and failed lol. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You say you tried, but [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: The question's a bit vague and shows little or no effort.  Doing a simple search for Java random numbers would list any number of possible approaches.  My basic approach would be to use something like `((int)Math.round(Math.random() * 3))`, this would result in a value of between 0 & 3.  It would be a simple task to maintain the images in an array...

Comment: Ok sorry i am still new in programing, thanks for the reply but I was mainly concerned with on how would be able to replace the current blank images on top of the previous one that was place. would you have to  create a new J button for every time the ActionEvent is performed? for example when the left mouse is clicked ex. new buttons[row][col] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("PipePictures/pipes0000.GIF"))

Comment: You may be looking for a [Java slide puzzle](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=java+slide+puzzle).